# How to simplify the call of a generic method, I created to convert from one type to another type across the different layer of my project

Tags: c#, generics

I want the second calling style should be similar to first calling style. Please see the details in my code. Any help is really appreciated.

Here is the code I am using.

// Calling Style of First Method

```
            var source = db.ThinkFeeds.Single(tf => tf.ID == 1);
            var target = new MyProduct.UIEntities.ThinkFeed();
            TypeConverter.ConvertBlToUi(source, target);
```

//Calling Style of Second method. Its really a weird calling style.

```
        var source = MyProduct.UIEntities.Book.GetBookByID(1);
        var target = new MyProduct.DTOEntities.Book();
        TypeConverter.ConvertUiToDto<MyProduct.UIEntities.Book, MyProduct.DTOEntities.Book, Book>(source, target);
```

//First Method

```
    public static void ConvertBlToUi<TBl, TUi>(TBl entitySource, TUi entityTarget)
    {

    }
```

//Second Method

```
    public static void ConvertUiToDto<TUi, TDto, TEntity>(TUi uiEntity, TDto dtoEntity)
        where TDto : DTOEntities.MyProductDTO<TEntity, TDto>
        where TEntity : EntityObject
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. [Generic Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), type inference:

> The compiler can infer the type parameters based on the method arguments you pass in; it cannot infer the type parameters only from a constraint or return value. Therefore ...

The first style you've shown is using type inference, but it's just a convenient shorthand. There are times (as here) where type inference cannot work, and so you have to supply the type parameters explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The `TEntity` type parameter in `ConvertUiToDto` is the one that is preventing type inference and forces you to specify explicitly all type parameters when calling this method. Unfortunately, this type parameter is used to put a type constraint on `TDto`:

```
where TDto : DTOEntities.LightsailDTO<TEntity, TDto>
```

As long as this constraint remains, you won't be able to remove `TEntity` from the declaration and used type inference when calling `ConvertUiToDto`.

Now for me the question is: why does the `LightsailDTO` require a `TEntity` type parameter? Aren't DTOs supposed to allow to transfer entities data without having to expose them?

Answer (score 0):

I actually asked a similar question and provided an answer myself.

[Is there a workaround to C# not being able to infer generic type arguments using type constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004000/is-there-a-workaround-to-c-sharp-not-being-able-to-infer-generic-type-arguments)

Basically, your only option is to pass the DTO twice, letting it infer each of the generic type parameters separately as follows:

```
public static void ConvertUiToDto<TUi, TDto, TEntity>(TUi uiEntity, TDto dtoEntity, DTOEntities.MyProductDTO<TEntity, TDto> dtoEntity2)
    where TDto : DTOEntities.MyProductDTO<TEntity, TDto>
    where TEntity : EntityObject
{

}
```

and call it as such:

```
var source = MyProduct.UIEntities.Book.GetBookByID(1);
var target = new MyProduct.DTOEntities.Book();
TypeConverter.ConvertUiToDto(source, target, target);
```