# C# Extend Generic Class in Method call

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to write a method that passes a generic argument that will extend a class with a generic argument, but I don't want to have to pass a second generic argument to the method.  Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do without passing two generic arguments?

```
// this base doesn't work because it expects a BaseReportViewModel<D> 
// I don't want to have to pass in two generic arguments from the child controller
// this is what I don't want to do: this.ReportView<Report1ViewModel, Report1Data>(viewModel);
// I want to ONLY have to pass in a single generic argument. 

public class BaseController {
  // the below line won't compile because it expects a generic type to be passed to BaseReportViewModel<>
  public ActionResult ReportView<T>(T viewModel) where T : BaseReportViewModel {
    viewModel.ReportGroup = this.ReportGroup;
    viewModel.ReportTitle = this.ReportTitle;
    return this.View(viewModel);
  }
}

public class ChildController {  
  var viewModel = new Report1ViewModel();               
  viewModel.Data = new Report1Data();
  return this.ReportView<Report1ViewModel>(viewModel);            
}

public class BaseReportViewModel<T> : BaseViewModel where T : ReportBaseData {
  public string ReportGroup { get; set; }
  public string ReportTitle { get; set; }
  public T Data { get; set; }
}

public class Report1ViewModel : BaseReportViewModel<Report1Data> {
}

public class Report1Data : BaseReportData {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
public ActionResult ReportView<T>(BaseReportViewModel<T> viewModel) 
    where T : ReportBaseData
```

Side note: You also should not need to pass type in `this.ReportView<Report1ViewModel>(viewModel);` call, just  `ReportView(viewModel);` should be enough as type should be derived from the argument.

Comment: Will the method lose the child type if I pass in the object as a BaseReportViewModel? And that means I'll need to pass in the type of the Data object into the ReportView method instead?

Comment: Trying this now... I'm thinking this could work! I'll respond shortly with feedback.

Comment: @AdamLevitt if you do `BaseViewModel m = new BaseReportViewModel<Report1Data>()` than you've already lost compile time information for child type and generic code will not be able to find correct type (as it is compile time operation). If you simply use `var m =  Report1ViewModel()` than it should be fine.

Comment: Yep, I'm using var.  With this approach, how can I then refer to an extended generic type then in the razor @model declaration?

Comment: @AdamLevitt not sure what is your quesition... Are you asking if you can use `@model Report1ViewModel` or `@model BaseReportViewModel<Report1Data>`? Or you are trying to make page that accepts all derived classes (like not-legal `@model BaseReportViewModel<T>`)?

Comment: Yeah I'd like to have a shared report header that can handle all of the derived classes of BaseReportViewModel.  I guess this isn't possible? Like @model T where T : BaseReportViewModel.  Same issue as above almost. In this shared header, I don't need the subclass fields, BUT it's telling me the item passed to the dictionary is the wrong type.

Comment: @AdamLevitt I think you should ask separate question as you need to show your views (assuming something like layout + header + model-specific partial view). Likely you'll be able to specify base class for header view and derived class for specific partial views.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help. You answered my initial question!

Comment: Checkout my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004000/is-there-a-workaround-to-c-sharp-not-being-able-to-infer-generic-type-arguments/14004001#14004001