# Generic constraint where T is a MyClass<U>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
class IntMyClass : MyClass<int> { }
class StringMyClass : MyClass<string> { }
class FloatFloatMyClass : MyClass<float, float> { }
class Container<T, U> where T : MyClass<U> { 
    List<U> List;

    Set(){
       List.First().Value1 = List.Last().Value1;    
    }
}

class Container<T, U, V> where T : MyClass<U, V> { 
    List<U> List;
    List<V> List2;

    Set()
       List.First().Value1 = List.Last().Value1;    
       List.First().Value2 = List.Last().Value2;    
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass{
    Container<IntMyClass> IntContainer;
    Container<FloatFloatMyClass> FloatFloatContainer;
}
```

However, the last part:

```
public class SomeOtherClass{
    Container<IntMyClass> IntContainer;
    Container<FloatFloatMyClass> FloatFloatContainer;
}
```

Gives an error for incorrect number of parameters. Is it possible for C# to infer that the 2nd parameter should be an `int` based on the `IntTuple` class?

Comment: Its seems *suspect* that you would want to inherit from `Tuple` like this anyway.

Comment: What you're doing with tuples is a bit concerning, but what you're trying to accomplish has a bit of a hacky workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004000/is-there-a-workaround-to-c-sharp-not-being-able-to-infer-generic-type-arguments
^This might help

Comment: Looking forward for the proposal to be implemented: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1349 ...

Comment: How many generic parameters does `MyClass` have? `MyClass<A>` and `MyClass<A,B>` would be different types.